# searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText not called

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone-developer-program

The *searchBar:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText* never called. The delegate is defined, the methods – **searchBarShouldBeginEditing:** and **searchBarTextDidBeginEditing**: works fine but the  **shouldChangeTextInRange** not called. I discovered that when setp in a method that use **alertview** and after I try to use the searchbar..the shouldChangeTextInRange is called...but before not

```
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     }

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
 return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 return YES;
}


-(BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
return  YES;
 }

 -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

  }
```

Comment: I did a test and put an alertview in view did load...Th searchBar worked...but I dont wanna an alertView :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have missed the code below in appDelegate , ***applicationDidFinishLauching***

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Now the SearchBar is working fine!